# Query table with a json column of list of dicts in a postgres table

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table that looks like

```
Col1 Col2   JsonCol3
A     B    [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}]
C     D    [{'id': 3}, {'id': 4}]
```

The JsonCol3 is a Json blob and contains a list of dicts

I want to transpose the table into

write a select query that gives me

```
A B 1 
A B 2
C D 3
C D 4
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON array in the JsonCol3 column can be expanded using the json_array_elements function in PostgreSQL, and it can then be joined with the other columns to complete the transformation. The query that achieves this is as follows:

```
SELECT
    Col1,
    Col2,
    (value->>'id')::int AS id
FROM
    your_table,
    json_array_elements(JsonCol3) AS value;
```